# How to override background-color for all classes using css?

Tags: css, primefaces, themes

I'm using a `CSS` theme that I'm not allowed to edit, I need a way to paint all the white `backgroud-color` with something  less shiny.

I'm new to `CSS`, what should I do to override the background-color for all classes using `CSS`?

Here is a screen shot, I'm using *Primefaces* to generate the web content hence I'm unable to change the provided `CSS`

[A screen shot of what I'm trying to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2rmp.png)

I already understand that every element has it's own class in the theme, but I don't know their names, nor which one of these classes provide the `background-color` for those elements, what I'm looking for is a simple way to repaint the white color in the whole page.

Comment: This question is either too broad or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: can I add a screen shot, to tell what I'm trying to do? @Paulie_D

Comment: @bttb Sure you can do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied.

And also:

> Specificity is based on the matching rules which are composed of CSS selectors of different sorts.

That means that the `CSS` would be applied depending of your browser and your `CSS Selectors` for that browser.

And you should also look at what [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#Selector_Types) has a higher specificity.

But as you want to override the `background-color`, that means to get the higher `CSS Selector` specificity I think what you are looking for is the [!important exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception).

Again from the documentation:

> this declaration overrides any other declarations.

that means that the property of CSS that you are going to set with `!important` exception will be applied overriding the rest of different configurations that has that property.

But also, you have to care about to abuse of that property:

> Using !important is bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets.

**What I recommend:**

- Try to set your `background-color` with `CSS Selectors` with higher specificity.
- If you cannot modify the property, and you have tried all the posibilities, then use `!important` exception.

Comment: I used 
`html {
 background-color: #d2f5ff !important;
}`
but this only change the background color of the page outside any other elements, now I learned about specificity I understand that those elements where the bk didn't change has a higher specificity than the !important exception!! @Error404

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot understand what is your problem now. Can you put an example of the code that you have right now or at least a simple example that shows the problem that you are having? A good webpage to put examples is https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I added more information to the question, please tell me if what I'm asking for is based on bad understanding of the concepts.

Comment: @bttb As I can see in your edit, you do not know how to see the class that each of the elements has. What browser are you using? If you are using `Google Chrome` you can right click on an element and click `Inspect` option or something similar. A new window will appear with all the `DOM` in it and the `CSS` on the right side so you can see what `CSS` has each element of the `DOM`. Let me know if you have any doubts about doing this.

Comment: I tried the inspection as you said, but I'm confused with the crossed out properties, and the faded ones. Still I need to change every ´white´ background, is there a way not to override every class? Like a selector for white, I will appreciate any thing not manual.

Comment: @bttb If you inspect on a particular element you can see the clases or IDs changes of CSS are associated **only** for that element. Look that it can be also properties that are inherited from other clases (of parents elements). Look at this link: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools to see how it works and the different parts that has the inspector of Google Chrome. Maybe it will help you to clarify your doubts.

Comment: I learned much from this answer, it took me time, but now I know it's the right answer for my question.

Comment: @bttb CSS seems very complicated in a first instance but when you start to understand how it works, it is very fast to learn it. 2 advice if you want to learn a lot of CSS and HTML: **1)** Do not use libraries. They will make the hard work for you and you will not learn the basis about CSS. **2)** Practice, practice and practice and finally you will get it. I am also learning CSS by the moment (since 3 months ago or something similar) and with a lot of practice I am getting it each day a bit more clear. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can paste this into the bottom of your page right before the  tag.

```
<script>
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#883377";
</script>
```

You can the change the `#883377` to whatever color you would like.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to change the white color only, is there a way even if it's a script or `JQ`? @Eli

Comment: @bttb Do you have a link to this screen?

Comment: there are a variety of classes, ids are generated by a framework so I can't depend on that.

Comment: These elements have to have some sort of consistent class name that the framework would call for styles. I would inspect element and view the class names of one element, then see if you can find that class name in any of your files. Once you find the non-generated class name, you can change it with the script (which would have to be tweaked), or change it with your own css so it overrides the current styles.

Comment: there are many classes, when I try to use the inspector in FireFox feel totally lost, I think they use a variety of names, is there a way to define `white` as another color globally??

Comment: You could search for #fff or #ffffff

Comment: how to search? and where? I'm not allowed to change the theme `CSS`? can I do it with JQ?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, and inspecting on firefox.

Comment: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-do-a-find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-in-eclipse.html

Comment: But you will not need to replace

Comment: I don't have access to the theme files, I can't change them :)

Comment: Do you have a link to this screen?